# How can I test this (interaction) pattern

Tags: statistics, regression, anova, interaction

[image]

Hi, I have some troubles understanding which analysis is suitable to test this expected pattern.
The idea here is that in Condition 1, the difference between A and B is higher, but small between C and IC. In Condition 2, the difference between C and IC should be higher, but lower between A and B. Ideally, I would like to test this via a three-way ANOVA (2x2x2), but as the graphs are parallel in both plots, it seems that there would not be a significant interaction. Does anyone have an idea? Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: What does it look like if you do a red graph (C) and a blue graph (IC), with AB x Condition shown on each graph?  Or what if you make a single graph with solid lines for Condition 1 and dotted lines for Condition 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proposed model seems to be something like:

```
RT ~ Condition * GroupAB * GroupCIC
```

Based on the plots provided, this should produce output with:

- no meaningful 3-way interaction, nor a meaningful 2-way interaction between `GroupAB` and `GroupCIC` since the lines are parallel in both conditions.
- A meaningful `Condition:GroupCIC` interaction, since the lines are further apart in condition 2 that condition 1
- A meaningful `Condition:GroupAB` interaction, since the slopes of the lines are different between the two conditions.

Comment: This is so helpful, thanks a lot!